# i need the particular tag value attached to the autoscaling group using the command

Tags: amazon-web-services

by using the below command i can able to get the details of my autoscaling group.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name my-ASG --region=eu-west-1
```

but I need the value of a particular tag value only instead of the whole data in windows terminal. can someone help me

Comment: Depending on what terminal youre using, you could use grep or jq to filter the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the tags for your ASG like the following.

```
aws autoscaling describe-tags --filters Name=auto-scaling-group,Values=my-asg-autoscaling --query 'Tags[].{Key: Key, Value: Value}'
```

Here is the result(dummy values)

```
[
    {
        "Key": "Env",
        "Value": "qa"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Function",
        "Value": "as"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "my-asg-autoscaling"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Project",
        "Value": "test"
    },
    {
        "Key": "VPC",
        "Value": "nonprod"
    },
    {
        "Key": "monitored",
        "Value": "non-prod"
    }
]
```

If instead you want to get a particular tag e.g **Function** in the example, you can get it with the following query.

```
aws autoscaling describe-tags --filters Name=auto-scaling-group,Values=my-asg-autoscaling --query 'Tags[?Key==`Function`].Value[]'
```

Comment: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeTags operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxx:assumed-role/xxx-xxx/i-xxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:DescribeTags because no identity-based policy allows the autoscaling:DescribeTags action

Comment: i was like getting the above error .. is that means i need to add any policy or something to the role.. because when i was running the below command aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=i-xxxx" it was working fine and giving the ec2 tags but when i was running the above command i was not getting the ASG tags

Comment: Maybe you have changed the policies attached to the role? In any case, you need `"ec2:DescribeTags"` in your `Action` part of the policy. Or you can give `ec2:*` this way you won't have this issue for certain.

Comment: aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name ms-ASG --query "AutoScalingGroups[-1].Tags[?Key==`url`].Value[]" --region=eu-west-1 --output text  ....i was able to get the tag by using this

Comment: yes, because you haven't set or not the correct region in your default profile(credentials).